# React Router v6 Authenticated Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I know this question has been washed multiple times. However, I was unable to get all my answers from multiple treads.

I do understand main concept of wrapping authenticated route into `Authorize` to be able to have check if user is authenticated before main route component will be loaded.

I have a question on router about this. Router expose property `loader` on he `Route` object. It is stated in documentation that you should be using this hook to get relative data for a route that is been activated. My question is, why cant we use this to check if user is been authenticated there? If this hook is been executed on every route change cant this be used to check user  store if user s authorized and circuit the operation?

Here is the sample structure

```
const route = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        Component: LoginComopnent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loader: {custom function here}
        children: [
          {
            path: 'home',
            Component: App
          }
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Comment: "My question is, why cant we use this to check if user is been authenticated there?" - Who or what says you can't? I think your question is based on a false premise/assumption.

Comment: @DrewReese I might word my question incorrectly. Its not that I `cant` use it. It just does not seem to be  a proper place to perform this operation.

Comment: I wouldn't put my auth logic in a route loader, but that doesn't mean you can't, or shouldn't. I'm not a fan of the loaders but i'd certainly agree they exist namely to fetch data for the route they're loading. I believe the docs still have examples for the`redirect` utility that reference handing 401/403 response statuses.

Comment: @DrewReese. That is understood. However, my question is, is there a hook or a function that can be run in the router `before` route has been activated. Goal is to short circuit navigation process if user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: the loader function and the component App will be loaded at the same time. However, if you use loader to check if user has been authenticated there, you will want the loader execute before the component is loaded.
Here is a proposal about `beforeLoader` which may match your need: [Loader + Action Context (Middleware)](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9564)

Comment: On the first time navigating to a route, the loaders run before the routed component is mounted and rendered. I don't really understand the point you are trying to make and I don't believe this answers the question.

Comment: Interesting, however it does not look like it was merged in. As you mentioned also, I do not like the fact that it will be called in parallel as it could result in not needed react lifecycle evens been triggered. if user is not authorized. it looks like I will either have to wrap it in `context` or create a wrapper component that will only render after authentication logic is performed .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).